# Traffic redirection and failover of ASA with multiple ISPs

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, dual-homed, route-map

I have two ISP connections on two Cisco 3900 routers, in front of Cisco asa 5525 x with firepower services firewall.
I want to configure the firewall to redirect traffic based on the source address
for example 192.168.1.0/24 when leaving the firewall after inspection and everything to go to R1 and the other subnet to go to R2 when leaving oustide interface of the firewall.

And also if ISP 1 goes down every traffic should go to R2 and vice versa by using IP SLA.
[image]

Comment: And what is your question? We're not going to build your entire configuration for you.

Comment: You also need to take into account asymmetric routing on the Internet if you are using NAT. Return traffic can come back to the wrong WAN router, and it will then be dropped because the translation entry is in the other router.

Comment: Teun Vink i don't want the whole configuration just a redirection part & ip sla.

Comment: You need to give us more info to go on.  We need to see sanitized configs of both routers, and the ASA, along with knowing which version of code they each are running, to know which features are supported in order to accomplish this.  There are a few ways this could be done, so we need the additional details to know which will work for you.  As it is, this is too vague and would result in guessing, which is off limits here.

Answer (score 0):

I'd share my 2 cents about the above configuration. **Single ASA & 2 routers might not be the ideal architecture.** For the goal you're trying to achieve, most implementations involve **2 ASAs configured in active/standby mode as shown below.**

[image]

You can easily punch a few [Policy Based Routing commands](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa94/config-guides/cli/general/asa-94-general-config/route-policy-based.html) and configure the **interface path for certain source and destination traffic.**

> And also if ISP 1 goes down every traffic should go to R2 and vice
>   versa by using IP SLA.

As to the ISP 1 going down scenario, you can just **configure the interface towards router 2 with greater Administrative Distance than the internet-facing interface on router 1.**
Doing so will create a preferred path to ISP 1 and reroute traffic to router 2 if ISP 1 fails.

Comment: Depending on the version of software on the ASA, PBR may not be an option, hence why I said (above) that we need more details (including the version of software) before we can give assistance, because without it, it's all guessing (which is off limits).

Comment: @JesseP. Yes! PBR is released in April 2016 version 9.4.1. I just assumed we're running something contemporary.

Comment: I know.  And I'd like to believe that they are, too, but we can't be sure until they actually say so.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. ASA version is 9.8(4)10.